# does spring jdbctemplate.batchUpdate() method closes the connection automatically? I can see jdbcTemplate.execute method closes it

Tags: spring, jdbc, connection, spring-batch

Please find below code:

```
JdbcUtils.closeStatement(stmt);
DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
```

Comment: It Close the Statement, not the Connection!! The Connection will be released and put back to the Connection pool

Comment: It depends. Yes it calls `close` on the `Connection` (actually the `DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());` does that) if it is a pooled connection it probably goes back to the pool, if it is a simple datasource it will probably close the connection. Although if you have proper transaction management then nothing will happen and closing/releasing the resources will be left to the transaction manager.

Comment: @Jens but it is just opening the connections and not closing. is there any way that we can close these explicityly?

Comment: It doesn't open the Connection. it "get" the Connection. Look into `DataSourceUtils` how it is implemented

Comment: @M.Deinum I am just creating data sources at spring boot application startup, not using any transaction manager to handle db connections. such case, how to handle these connections manually? I am using spring jdbc temlate which is closing connections for execute method but not for batchUpdate method. please suggest.

Comment: @Jens But for every jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate method hit, connection size is increasing. no way it is getting decreased.

Comment: This question is not related to the `batch-file` tag. I suggest you to remove it...

Comment: @Aacini removed batch-file tag